# How to call one method within another method in TypeScript Class

Tags: typescript

Thanks to all who help. This problem is driving me a little nuts (and yes, I've searched). I am getting the "is not a function" error.

I feel like this should be easy.  I am simply attempting to call one method from another method is a ts class.  I am trying to use an arrow function (not shown) which is a little new to me but I cannot get anything to work.  All help is appreciated.

```js
namespace ScriptDemo
{
    export class FunctionExample
    {
        Counter: number;

        CalculateStuff(): void
        {
            this.Counter++;
            this.UpdatePage(this.Counter);
        }

        UpdatePage(counter: number): void
        {
            let label: HTMLElement = <HTMLElement>document.getElementById("output-label");
            label.innerHTML = counter.toString();
        }
    }

    window.onload = function ()
    {
        let functionExample = new FunctionExample();
        let button: HTMLButtonElement = <HTMLButtonElement>document.getElementById("UpdateCounterButton");
        button.addEventListener("click", functionExample.CalculateStuff);
    };
}
```

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIOXe.png)

Comment: on which line  you are getting error

Comment: Replace `button.addEventListener("click", functionExample.CalculateStuff);` by `button.addEventListener("click", () => functionExample.CalculateStuff());`

Comment: And replace `Counter: number;` with `Counter = 0;`

Comment: Paleo - thanks.  I'd like to know why this arrow function solves the problem....

Comment: Because with your original code you loose the `this` binding. https://hackernoon.com/understanding-javascript-the-this-keyword-4de325d77f68

Comment: @RedBirdOBX See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this With ES5 (classes in Javascript are ES6 and higher) this is determined by usage. With classes this is auto assigned tot eh elexical context (the object that gets created) and cannot be changed. You use an arrow function when you want to capture this like other oo languages else you would need to use Bind().

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is the line:

```
button.addEventListener("click", functionExample.CalculateStuff);
```

It's not a typescript issue, the same thing would happen in plain Javascript if you passed `instance.CalculateStuff` as a callback`.

This will take the function `CalculateStuff` out of the class and call it with `this` set to `undefined`. Either use an arrow function to ensure `this` is preserved correctly, or use `bind`.

Comment: Not `null` but `undefined` (in strict mode).